# Open menu thing on android

Tags: android, menu

on android phones there is a button at the bottom left. this usually opens up a menu. what is the code for this. Its okay to lead me to another post instead of posting a long answer here. sorry Im asking. I understand if there are other posts like this one.  I just couldnt seem to find one. ill delete this one when  done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the developer guide on menu :) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

To specify the options menu for an activity, override onCreateOptionsMenu() (fragments provide their own onCreateOptionsMenu() callback). In this method, you can inflate your menu resource (defined in XML) into the Menu provided in the callback. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

To handle click events:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```